# How to see file handles like with "lsof -l"?

Tags: unix, file-handling, file-descriptor

I did the commands ([source](http://en.flossmanuals.net/CommandLineIntro/StandardFiles)):

```
$ exec 3>/tmp/thirdfile
$ exec 4>/tmp/fourthfile
$ echo drib >&3
$ echo drab >&4
$ echo another drib >&3
$ echo another drab >&4
$ exec 3>&-
$ exec 4>&-
```

How can I see the file handles, something like with `lsof -l`?

Comment: Have you considered *reading the source* of lsof for the system you are interested in? There are few enough commercial closed-source unixes still in use that you should tell us if that is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand, why not just use lsof:

```
lsof -p $$
```

`$$` being a shell variable that holds the shell's process ID

You can also limit to just file descriptors like:

```
lsof -a -d0-65535 -p $$
```

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, you can do something like `ls -l /proc/$$/fd`, which will show you what file descriptors are open in your shell.

Of course, substitute `$$` with other numbers to inspect other processes (at least, the ones you own).