# Get list of files used by a process and all its child process

Tags: linux

Parent Process

forks child process1
forks child process2
.... so on

Each process has some files as input and produces some files as output.
This set of output files is used by another child process and so on.

How can we get the following information at run-time:

1. Which files are given input to a process.
2. Which files are produced as output.

To solve this problem suppose we have accessibility to code binary only. We can not look into the source code.

I think can we use an `strace` like utility, but I don't know how can it help.

Comment: You can use lsof and filter descriptors using grep.

Comment: `strace -e trace=file -f -o trace.log parent_program` will produce a list of every file-related system call made by the process and its children. But be warned, there's a lot of output, and stripping out all the dynamic libraries, device nodes, configuration files and other things might be significant work... Using `-e trace=open` instead might be useful, but it catches a different set of calls. Not sure which is more relevant to what you're asking without more information...

Comment: Try `inotify` or `lsof` tool.

Comment: See: [How to see file handles like with "lsof -l"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1338877/55075)